# Adding Objective C Syntax Highlighting to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, winobjc

I started to try out the new Windows Bridge for iOS (Project Islandwood). The samples work fine, but there is no code highlighting at all.
I found a VS Extension called "objc-syntax-highlighting" in the bin folder and was wondering if this adds code highlighting. But when I try to run it it says

> VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not
>   installable on any currently installed products.

I found the following lines in the error log

> 8/7/2015 2:19:21 PM -     Supported Products : 
>   8/7/2015 2:19:21 PM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
>   8/7/2015 2:19:21 PM -           Version : [12.0]

Any chance to install this on VS 2015?

Cheers!

Comment: Please create and add the Tag winobjc :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, there is currently a bug in the extension. But it works when opened the Extension file (it is a zip file) and added my VS Version to the vsixmanifest:
I changed this

```
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[12.0]" />
  </Installation>
```

to this

```
  <Installation>
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[12.0]" />
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[14.0]" />
  </Installation>
```